# Задать дату и время

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при помощи подобной конструкции задать дату (текущая дата минус один день) и время равное 19:00:00 ?

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(java.util.Calendar.getInstance.getTime().getTime())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 или выше :

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1L)
        .withHour(19).withMinute(0).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime);
```

Для более ранних версий:

```
Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);        
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);  
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но можно ли обойтись без LocalDateTime? т.к. jasper report не поддерживает его.

Comment: @Alex мне не очень часто приходилось сталкиваться с java.util.Calendar и java.util.Date в силу того, что это , на мой взгляд, откровенный позор Java. Посему до версии 8 активно использовался joda time, а потом java.time. Посему единственное решение, которое я могу предложить, можете найти в измененном ответе